# I don't know how to use for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

Hi I am kite to programming and there is something in my mind I can't comprehend about `for` loops.

I understand basic type for example `for i in range(10)` but I saw something that we can also write some codes the beginning of the loop for instance `[list[i::step] for i in range(step)]` it was about split a list steps. But generally I can't grab this topic.

Can anyone explain how it does work by examples? Please provide simple examples because I am new.

Comment: Are you asking about for loops(`[for <name> in <iterable>]`) or list slicing(`list[statr:stop:step]`)?

Comment: which bit are you unclear about exactly? list comprehension? splicing?

Comment: It's called list comprehensions,http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk

Comment: This is called "list comprehension" and is described in every Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not really specific. Basically both for loops you are mentioning are doing the same thing.

```
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
```

gives back

```
1
2
...
9
```

the same is achieved by

```
[print(i) for i in range(10)]
```

This is preferred if you have a very short loop and you want your code to stay clear.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that the "for" word is used in two different ways:

- To define loops as in `for i in range(10): print(i)`
- To define list comprehension as in ``` evens = [ 2*i for i in range(10) ]